# Non-rechargeable 9V battery with diode between 12V car battery

Tags: batteries, diodes, battery-operated

I have a microcontroller which is powered by a car battery, voltage is stepped down to 3.3V using a voltage regulator.  However if someone cuts the cord to the car battery the microcontroller has a local 9V battery inside its control box that is tied to the same header as the 12V battery.  This can power the board for a few days..

Obviously I cannot directly connect the 9V battery+ terminal to the 12V+ terminal, and because I never want to use the 9V battery unless I have no access to the 12V I have opted for the following circuit.  I am curious if this is dangerous though, I don't want to start any fires and this will be hooked up for months at a time..

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I have a microcontroller which is powered by a car battery, voltage is
> stepped down to 3.3V using a voltage regulator.*

If that is a linear regulator then, using [PMEG3050 Schottky diodes](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMEG3050EP.pdf) on the 9 volt battery feed should/could be avoided i.e. swapped for a regular silicon diode. Schottky diodes ought to be avoided because of their leakage current because, there is a slight chance that the 12 volt can trickle several tens of mA into the 9 volt battery at higher ambient temperatures. This may by fine but it may also be problematic depending on the details in the data sheet for the 9 volt battery.

Schottky diode leakage current graph: -

[image]

I would also put the fuse on the 12 volts straight after J103 rather than after D103 as this minimizes the risk of any component failing (such as J102), shorting out and, causing a fire. In fact, I'd probably consider an in-line fuse from the battery before it connects into J103.

This may also be necessary on the 9 volt line but, if it's one of those little PP3 batteries, it won't be necessary.

Comment: And since the 9-V battery is being dropped to 3.3, the increased voltage drop of the silicon diode won't be a problem.

Comment: I have been looking at: MFR#: RFN1LAM6STFTR as an alternative based on these suggestions.  Its leakage current is about 1uA

Comment: I'd put a diode in the 12V supply too. You don't want a short to ground draining your 9V battery and preventing it from providing backup.

Comment: @Feynman137 yes it's a better choice regarding leakage current.